# My email wont send iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to send a email through my app using this code but when I check my inbox (after entering my own email of course) nothing shows up. Do you know why this may be happening from looking at my code?

```
- (IBAction)email:(id)sender {


    MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    [composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        [composer setToRecipients: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: self.emailField.text, nil]];
        [composer setSubject: self.emailSubField.text];
        [composer setMessageBody: self.EmailTextField.text isHTML:NO];
        [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
        [self presentViewController:composer animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }

}
```

Comment: Implement the required delegate method and see what the result is. And be sure to test on a real iOS device.

Comment: if i test it on the ios simulator will it work

Comment: No. The simulator can't send email.

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems because I didn't test it on a real IOS device, just a simulator. Thank you to @rmaddy for making that clear @rmaddy.